# Divergence of a series using perturbation method to solve a 2nd order polynomial

Tags: perturbation-theory

Consider the following equation

$$x^2-2(1+e)x+1-e=0$$

As part of an H.W assignment I'm requested to attempt and find the roots using perturbation theory, and compare to the exact solution.

When I substitute to $x(e)=\sum_{i=1}^n e^na_n$ and take up to first order in $e$ I obtain
$$e^0(a_0-1)^2+e^1(2a_0a_1-2(a_0+a_1)-1)$$
by comparing the coefficients of $e$ to zero I get
$$a_0=1$$
$$a_1=\frac{1+2a_0}{2(a_0-1)}$$
which immediately shows that the series converges.

I'm trying to understand why the perturbation method does not work.

When I look at the roots of the exact solution, they seems quite close to the zero'th order solution ($x=a_0=1$)

[image]

I'm quite sure that the reason it pointed out in the proximity between the roots, but can not explain it in mathematical terms.

Can anyone please advise?

Comment: Are you missing a $x$ for the middle term? And did you mean that $a_1$ is not defined for $a_0=1$?

Comment: @MachineLearner, yes tnx.

Comment: When you get an inconsistent equation it usually means your assumption about the choice of gauge functions is incorrect. You assumed that the roots were of the form $x_0+\epsilon x_1+\ldots$, but this isn't the case here. Instead, use dominant balance to the find the correct power $\alpha$ for the expansion $x=1+\epsilon^\alpha x_1$ (since you know $x_0=1$ already).